# Notifications during a file download

Tags: 7, notifications

As a newcomer to Drupal 7, I'm trying to understand how auditing and events can be used together.

For example, I have a content type of document, which is basically a name field and a file.  I would like an email to go out whenever an authenticated user downloads the document and also have a report that shows how ( and when ) downloaded the document.  Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way ( modules, design patterns, etc ) to go about setting this up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Download Count](http://drupal.org/project/download_count) can produce file download statistics.

Additionally, because Download Count has [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) integration, you can create a Rule that will send an e-mail when a file is downloaded.

Comment: I didn't know 'Download Count' existed.  Great find!  The Rules module by itself may even be able to accomplish the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by creating a workflow rule that emailed the group of users whenever the node holding the content is viewed.
This also means that any issues around not having google analytics is resolved.
Finally, the emails match the auditing that is available to the administrator so that is used as a final stop.

Answer (score -1):

A couple thoughts and approaches.

I have tracked file downloads before, but I did mine using Google analytics and setting goals. You can easily track what is clicked when and get very page specific. Within google analytics the reporting is done for you, much better than anything Drupal could ever provide, and it can even email you when your 'goal' is met (which could be as little as one download).  Check out GA goal conversions, which specifically have instructions to track downloads, even. http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55580

If you want to go a Drupal route, then perhaps Ubercart or Drupal Commerce? An ecommerce module would require a person to download 'buy' the file and then download it after 'payment' is complete. If you are giving this away for free, then of course the price is 0, but, full tracking is available within drupal and notifications sent out consistently.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks - for that, will take a look.  One thing that I can't do from G.A. is use drupal specific data such as the authenticed drupal user that performed the file download.

Comment: hmm one thing you could do is use Path Auto (URL Aliases) and, when on the page of the file as well as confirmation page for download, use the 'user' token as part of the URL for that specific content type. So, for example, file/%username%/get.zip would be file/blue928/get.zip. those would allow a way to track in google. Hmm now that I think about it you could probably click everyone's every click that way.

Comment: The problem with relying on Google is that the users can simply defeat the reporting suite with plugins such as ghostery.